# How to change logo alone in email templates

Tags: email, transactional-mail

Am working in magento1.9.2.3.I just want to change the only the logo in the email transactions. Can it be done through admin panel without touching anything at frontend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Backend :

```
System > Configuration > General > Design > Transactional Emails > Logo Image
```

And easily pick your logo image from there.

[image]

The image will be uploaded here /media/email/ sometime the permissions will be `640` you need to change this to `644`

Comment: hey thank you.. I Identified the option.. but not ablle to upload my image. when I choose an image from my local machine it is been broken.

Comment: Please review your Magento folder permission

Comment: hey how to give folder permission. Can you please help me on that?

Comment: try this : find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
chmod -R o+w media

Comment: be careful with this

Comment: hey i dont think it as file permission. Because i was able to choose favicon from my local machine.

Comment: try with GIF image first and save, if it is not working can you right click on the broken image and copy the link and post it here please

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: but the image is broken.